# Convert bytes(with escaped hex) to escaped hex string

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02'
```

How can I convert it to:

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02'
```

or alternatively:

```
b'\x00\x1f\x00>\x00]\x00|\x00\x9b\x00\xba'
```

to

```
'\x00\x1f\x00>\x00]\x00|\x00\x9b\x00\xba'
```

I tried using `codecs.decode` , but couldn't find any way to leave it with the escaped hex format

I couldn do something similar like that:

```
''.join([hex(x).replace('0x', "\\x") for x in b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00'])
```

but it does seem like a work-around

Comment: What python version are you running? I used b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02'.decode(), returning the string '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02' in python3.8

Comment: The version I use is python3

Comment: If you decode `b'\x00'`, are you expecting a string containing the single null character, or the string consisting of ``\``, `x`, `0`, `0`?

Comment: I expect the exact sequence, without the b' prefix

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. `b'` is not part *of* the string; it's just how Python renders a `bytes` value.

Answer (score 0):

Latin-1 will decode any bytes to str without error:

```
>>> bs = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02'
>>> bs.decode('latin-1')
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02'
>>>
```